# How to define correct XPath location?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I was set ssnid & sinid as invisible fields.but both are still shows in my view.seems issue with XPath location.!

Anyone can help me to sort out ?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <!-- 1st part of the sim_view start -->
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="madulsima_plucker_form">
            <field name="name">madulsima.plucker.form</field>
            <field name="model">madulsima.plucker</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.view_employee_form" />
            <field name="type">form</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <notebook position="inside">
                    <page string="Madulsima Plucker Fields">
                        <field name="reg_no" />
                        <field name="worker_name" />

                        <xpath expr="/form/notebook/page/group/field[@name='ssnid']"
                            position="attributes">
                            <attribute name="invisible">True</attribute>
                        </xpath>
                        <xpath expr="/form/notebook/page/group/field[@name='sinid']"
                            position="attributes">
                            <attribute name="invisible">True</attribute>
                        </xpath>

                    </page>
                </notebook>
            </field>
        </record>

        <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_plucker_registration">
            <field name="name">Plucker Registration</field>
            <field name="res_model">madulsima.plucker</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">form</field>
        </record>


        <menuitem id="menu_madulsima_plucker" name="Madulsima/Checkroll" />

        <menuitem id="menu_madulsima_plucker_registration" name="Plucker Registration"
            parent="menu_madulsima_plucker" action="action_plucker_registration" />
    </data>
</openerp>
```

i posted my whole code in view.xml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The root elements in the `arch` field of an [inherited view](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/03_modules_3.html#inheritance-in-views) are *locators* which are supposed to identify an element in the parent view, on which an operation can then be performed according to the special `position` attribute.

A locator must have a `position` attribute and can be either:

- an `<xpath>` element with an `expr` attribute containing a valid
  [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-Introduction) expression for locating a single element in the parent view;
- any valid view element from the parent view;

An inherited view can have multiple root elements, in order to perform several alteration to the parent view.

Your example is incorrect because you have nested several *locators*: your `xpath` elements are inside the `page` element. Notice that 3 elements have a `position` attribute in your inherited view: the `notebook` element and the 2 `xpath` elements. They all need to be at the top of the view architecture, for example:

```
       <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <notebook position="inside">
               <!-- ... elements you want to add inside the parent notebook -->
            </notebook>
            <xpath expr="/form/notebook/page/group/field[@name='ssnid']"
                   position="attributes">
                <attribute name="invisible">True</attribute>
            </xpath>
            <xpath expr="/form/notebook/page/group/field[@name='sinid']"
                   position="attributes">
                <attribute name="invisible">True</attribute>
            </xpath>
        </field>
```

PS: if you're not familiar with [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-Introduction), you should look online for a quick reference or cheat sheet, such as [this one](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/xpath,-css,-dom-and-selenium-the-rosetta-stone/).

Comment: thanks Odony...for ur explanation
very useful,i think not only me anyone who sees this post after us  :-)